# cmake 3.11.4 not starting properly?

Tags: cmake

Cmake used to work perfectly in my linux, but I found out recently it is not working (I don't remember from when exactly).

When I type "cmake", it doesn't output anything and stuck forever.
In order to understand the problem, I made a minimal CMakeLists.txt file:

```
Message(test)
```

but still not working with no standard output.

Currently I have no clue what is happening.
I appreciate for suggestions/solutions.
Thank you!

Environment:

- cmake 3.11.4
- Arch Linux - 4.17.10-1 x864

Comment: What happens when you try `cmake --version`?

Comment: It just shows the version 3.11.4